# Android Issue::More than one file was found with OS independent path 'androidsupportmultidexversion.txt' "error"

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx, android-gradle-3.0, androidx-test

I am getting this issue while compiling my project I have tried a few solutions for that and that is

[More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license)

[On gradle:3.0.0 More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/ASL2.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956341/on-gradle3-0-0-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf)

https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

https://www.bswen.com/2019/11/android-More-than-one-file-was-found-with-OS-independent-path-META-INF-DEPENDENCIES.html

[Error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958884/error-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-dependenc)

['More than one file was found with OS independent path project.properties' Error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630015/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-project-properties-error)

[Gradle Error : More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310527/gradle-error-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-a)

https://dorbae.github.io/android/troubleshooting/Android-Troubleshooting-Morethanonemetainf/

https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-java/issues/128

but nothing worked for me
anyone having any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue you can use this link as an reference

([Getting Androidx library issue even though its not enabled in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228364/getting-androidx-library-issue-even-though-its-not-enabled-in-android-project/63246890#63246890))

**or**

You can directly Try to change minimum Android version >= 21 in your build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
}
```