# Getting Androidx library issue even though its not enabled in android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, androidx

I am getting this issue

```
This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.

The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
```

I keep getting this error and I have been searching the internet to figure out what is wrong and I cannot find anything

"And I can't use Androidx library in my project "

Comment: android.useAndroidX=true add this to gradle file.

Comment: no, i don't want to use androidx in my project that's the boundation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many of the answers on SO on this problem it has been suggested to add exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' and some other excludes. However none of these worked for me. In my case scenario was like this:

I had added this in dependancies:

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```

And also I had added this in gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Both of these I had added, because I was getting build error 'cannot find symbol class Nullable' and it was suggested as solution to this on some of answers like here

However, eventually I landed up in getting error:

```
 More than one file was found with OS independent path 'androidsupportmultidexversion.txt'
```

No exclude was working for me. Finally I just removed

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```

from build.grdle file.
and finally I got rid of this

( [More than one file was found with OS independent path 'androidsupportmultidexversion.txt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227992/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-androidsupportmultidexver) )

```
"More than one file was found with OS..." build error.
```

I wasted hours of mine.But didn't found solution of this.
Then i just change my project

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

**to**

```
 minSdkVersion 21
```

And finally i am able to build my apk file without any error